# How make the static imports faster in IntelliJ / Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, junit

Every time I create a new test, the first time I add static methods for the testing suites like (`Asserts.assertTrue()`, or `Mockito.mock()`), I get the error because the import is missing.

Since this problem is pretty repetitive. I'm trying to speed it up.

Currently I am using:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (A floating menu appears with two options: `create method assertTrue` and `static import method org.junit.Assert.assertTrue`)
- <kbd>▼</kbd> (To select the second option)
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Can I configure something to make those imports more fluid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try to edit your template

**Go to File->Settings->Editors->File and Code Templates**

here find your unit test template and modify it as you wish
[image]

Once you have modified it all you future test would be with modifications

Comment: Yeah, that is what i was looking for, currently android studio automatically deletes the wildcard import on creation (since it is not being used). Any ideas to avoid it? I'll search

Comment: It delete it when you create file first time, or when you formatted code?

Comment: I think it is because the "Optimize imports on the fly" option. Dont know if you can't avoid the deletion of wildcard imports with this option

Comment: It looks like in ``java`` code style exists some rule that tells AndroidStudion  remove static Wildcard imports, try to discover next section of settings 

``File->Settings->Editor->Code Style-> Java`` or near here

Comment: Oh, yep, here is tabs with name ``Imports`` try to add you rule here, and discover applied changes

Answer (score 1):

Unless you object to using wildcard imports, `static import org.junit.Assert.*;` will sort you out nicely.

The recommendation is to use static imports sparingly (and wildcards even more so), but unit testing is one place where that becomes quite common and is somewhat risk-free.

Comment: What is the faster way to make all my tests to have the org.junit.Assert.* and the org.mockito.Mock.* imports?